# Selecting viewchild with 1 hash selection in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, viewchild

Is there a trick to select multiple tag within same level with same tag?

```
<div #el></div>
<div #el></div>
<div #el></div>
```

It's always given "Reference "#el" is defined several times" error message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't give same id to multiple element.
It will select first element only.

Comment: @Dhavalkansagara So is there another way to make it like that? [here](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e) is a link to make what i want, but this method is too complicated to sync with my current code..

Comment: You can't , with your attempt with ViewChildren & QueryList, you will get  a single item only with a template variable like you do, but it will give a list if you use these for component/directive

Comment: What's the purpose of using the same variable references? Could you use a wrapper and give it the unique variable reference as workaround?

Comment: @Vega yeah I did what you told, just want to make more simple.. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Below approach is working fine for me for multiple elements with appropriate selector.

I have an requirement to load the popup modal dynamically from code base and also perform some actions like Minimize, Maximize, Close and Resize. At that time I have to pick the any one opened modal to perform some operation and I came up with this solution.

Below is my HTML, In which I used #dynamicPopupContentPlaceHolder as selector for div tag.

[image]

Firstly, Need to add the QueryList in component from angular/core library as shown below.

[image]

Finally, In the component file I used the QueryList (Contains the array of children) to get all the children using below way.

[image]

At end I used the widgetSelector variable to get the last child from array using below way.

```
let _targetSelector = this.widgetTargets.last;
```

Comment: Can someone please edit this answer to include code rather than images?  As someone who is blind, it's entirely unreadable as written.

Comment: Please don't put images that contains code. Copy/paste the code instead.

Answer (score 1):

Include **ViewChildren**.

```
import {Component, ViewChildren} from 'angular2/core'
```

Now you can use the following code.

```
@ViewChildren('el') components:QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Comment: I tried that first but only select the first element

Comment: @ViewChild will select one but @ViewChildren('el') components:QueryList<ElementRef>; this will select all.

Comment: @Dhavalkansagara @ViewChildren('el') components:QueryList<ElementRef>  is only a single element. `Note: In this case, it will make more sense to use the @ViewChild decorator because this is only a single element.`

Comment: he need to select 3 div element with #el name. So we need to use @ViewChildren.

Comment: @Dhavalkansagara for a template variable it wont work, just got one element. But for component or directive that would work.

Comment: Check this here https://gist.github.com/benfoley/7a73f18bc54a5dc2ac92393731b31b46

Answer (score 0):

Oh nevermind.. I got another way, but not so neat

```
<div #el>
  <div el></div>
  <div el></div>
  <div el></div>
</div>
```

Then for select all use querySelectorAll

```
@ViewChild('el') element: ElementRef;
this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[el]')
```

Thanks All